# Edit or remove the permission from app info page while installing the application

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have a requirement that edit the app info page of android while we trying to install the app manually, I have did google a lot and didn't find anything on google, so please help it is possible or not , can we edit this page, I am adding image below for your reference

[image: ScreenShot of information page]

Comment: IMHO, so the list is generated automatically that we can nothing do with it. *Take pictures and videos* is a permission's category title.

Comment: @hata Actually I am just using pictures not videos that why we want to remove video from title

Comment: @NishaAgrawal I see but they consist of a single group as a permission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short Answer** : You cannot do that!!!

**Detailed answer** : Permissions are meant to let users know what the developer is trying to access from their devices. If the developer can manipulate the permission text, how will the user know what all things the app will access? So you shouldn't try to do that and you are not allowed to do that.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't edit. this information coming according to your manifeste and if you change this text you can cheat users by giving wrong permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Editing this page?

No it is not possible to edit this page. It is handeled by android and you have no control on it but you may have some chances in android version 6.

Due to [this link](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en),  we have some changes in permissions. In android 6 we don't have this page anymore, the user should accept permissions on run time and for showing permissions you can buildd your own alert dialog so there you can set your own sentence for permissions but not on that page.

Answer (score 0):

No because user must know the permission for access before installing application. we can not customise permission due to user security, At the time of app installation user get details about permission.

Comment: Add more information to make more complete your answer.